Remote SSH into Server 24.04 LTS offline
I've just freshly installed Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS after running 22.04 LTS.
I've set up all of my drives etc and SSH with public key authentication using ed25519 keys.
My problem is that I can SSH into the server from within my network, but I am unable to remote connect from outside my network.
I've set a static IP for the server and ensured that I am forwarding the port via my router's control panel. The problem is that when I check my router it shows the server as offline.
I added the port to ufw and allowed SSH through ufw but that hasn't changed anything.
With 22.04 LTS it was pretty simple of just adding the rules to ufw and forwarding the public port to the local port on the ip address of the server, but that doesn't seem to be working with 24.04 LTS
ETA - I've reset all the details in the router and it works until I restart the server. And I can still connect from within the local network regardless. The only thing that is different from this install as opposed to my 22.04 install is that I have changed the public key authentication from RSA to ed25519. Could this be the issue?

"My problem is that I can SSH into the server from within my network, but I am unable to remote connect from outside my network." This is usually considered sufficient proof that there is nothing wrong with your Ubuntu Server. It works. Firewall rules are already correct. Configuration is already correct. You can ssh into it. You just cannot ssh into it through your router, which suggests the next place to revisit.

I've reset all the details in the router and it works until I restart the server. And I can still connect from within the local network regardless.
The only thing that is different from this install as opposed to my 22.04 install is that I have changed the public key authentication from RSA to ed25519. Could this be the issue?

make sure your isp service plan allowz incoming connections.

It does. Everything was working fine on 22.04 LTS, it's only since the upgrade that it's not doing it

It would be helpful if you could narrow down the type of failure - connection refused? timeout? connects but fails to authenticate?

Try to ssh from outside your home network using the command ssh -vvvv your_username@<external IP address or domain name>. The 4 vs are the most important part. Then copy and paste the output into your question above. Finally format the pasted output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

If you can ssh from within your home network, login to your 24.04 server and enter the command systemctl status ssh.service and add the output to your question above formatted as code.

"I have changed the public key authentication from RSA to ed25519. Could this be the issue?" This should not be a problem. I have switched from RSA to ed25519 while in 22.04 and currently using it in 24.04.

The first step would be to confirm that your server has a default gateway set. Can it reach the internet?
The second step would be to provide an actual firewall rules dump. It's possible that you've configured the system to allow SSH from the local network, but not from the internet at large.
If none of those are the culprit I would double check the router with a benign port that is unlikely to be filtered. Can you forward that port to SSH? Can you forward it to another service such as Apache?
And of course.. have you tried rebooting your router?
